# Keytool facebook app for android not working on device

Tags: android, facebook, smartphone, keytool

I've been trying for 4 hours to discover how to use the keytool stuff. My app works so well in the emulator. I've tried almost all of tutorials and tips in StackOverflow, Google and others.
Now, I'm really frustrated, because this is my first time trying to use facebook stuff on the device.

Please, does anyone have a tutorial for beginners to help me solve this?

I'm using Windows 7 and Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create custom key-store, if you want to work your apps in device.

```
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html
```

Visit two link page. [link1](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-1) [link2](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-2) how to use Facebook sdk.. use custom keystore instead of debug keystore. I just hope that this time your apps will work.